# cannot assign to return value because function 'operator[]' returns a const value

Tags: c++, vector

I am writing a function in C++ that doubles all the numbers in a vector. My code is:

```
std::vector<int> maps(const std::vector<int> & values) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) 
    {
        values[i] = values[i] * 2;
    }
    return values;
}
```

However this gives the error:

> error: cannot assign to return value because function 'operator[]' returns a const value
>
> values[i] = values[i] * 2;

I don't understand this error or what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `const std::vector<int> & values` means *"I promise I won't modify `values`"* which contradicts what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand this error...

The error says that the assignment `values[i] = ...` is illegal

> or what is wrong with my code.

You pass `values` as `const` vector. This lets the code inside `maps` to read `values` at index `i`, but not write back a new value.

You can fix it by copying the array first, and doing modifications to the copy. It can be done implicitly by removing `const` and `&` from the signature of `maps`:

```
std::vector<int> maps(std::vector<int> values)
```

Now that `values` is passed by value, C++ makes a copy for you before entering `maps`.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the vector as `const` and you are trying to modifying it. Remove `const` qualifier if you want to modify it.